# Mensa Question - squares with shapes and lines within them

Tags: pattern, visual, sequence

What's the next square?

[image]

It was extracted from an IQ test of [Mensa](https://www.mensa-idf.org/?action=tests_exemples). 
There is no trap except I don't know if it can be solved.

There's some French before the question:

> Parmi les 5 figures proposées, laquelle prolonge la série ?

which translates to:

> Of the 5 figures proposed, which extends the series?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The first figure has 5 sides. The second has 6 sides and 2 rows outside. Let's assume that this 2 rows are the number of sides to subtract. So the second figure would have 4 sides and the third would have 4 - 1 = 3 sides. In this sequence, we have 5, 4, 3 and expect the next number will be 2. 
> The answer "a" have 3 - 1 = 2 sides, so I think  it's the answer.

Comment: So the square following the answer contains a rare two-sided polygon.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern could be:

> A normal figure has 5 corners. A better figure has +1 corner and a = sign in bottom right corner. A poorer figure has -1 corner and a - sign in bottom right corner.

The next figure could be

> d

Comment: Sorry, somebody change the sentence, we don't search wich one could go with the others. The real sentence is what is the next square.

Answer (score 1):

In the first three figures,

> the total number of lines
> (edges of the polygon plus unattached lines in the corner)
> is equivalent to 2 mod 3, and all quadrilaterals are rectangles.

The only one of the options that conforms to the above is

> e.

Comment: I sit back and wait, anticipating that the other two options will be supported also.

Comment: The lines in the corner are irrelevant. What counts is the number of sides in the polygon. The sequence is: 5, 6, 4, 5, 3, 4. Therefore, the next in the series is the only five-sided figure: c. Give me a minute, and I'll see if I can come up with a rationale for b.